# How to store data from SmartGWT ListGrid?

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, google-cloud-datastore, smartgwt, listgrid

I've been searching for hours but I couldn't find an answer to my question: I've set up a `ListGrid` similar to the one shown here ([Link](http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#grid_frozen_editing)). Right now I am using a XML-File as data source (default rows) just like in the example. It is also possible to add and delete rows to/from the grid.

Therefore I would like to store every user's data from the grid in a data store (Google Datastore). So I need to read all the rows of the current user as Strings. What would be a good way to do that? I already tried the following, but without success:

```java
    ListGrid componentsGrid = new ListGrid();
    componentsGrid.setWidth(500);
    componentsGrid.setHeight(224);
    componentsGrid.setCellHeight(22);
    componentsGrid.setDataSource(ComponentsXmlDS.getInstance());

    componentsGrid.setAutoFetchData(true);
    componentsGrid.setCanEdit(true);
    componentsGrid.setModalEditing(true);
    componentsGrid.setEditEvent(ListGridEditEvent.CLICK);
    componentsGrid.setListEndEditAction(RowEndEditAction.NEXT);
    componentsGrid.setAutoSaveEdits(false);
    layout.addMember(componentsGrid);

        //First try
        componentsGrid.fetchData();                 
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Components: "+ componentsGrid.getResultSet().get(0).getAttribute("componentType"));

        //Second try                    
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Components: "+ componentsGrid.getAllFields());

       // Third try
       logger.log(Level.INFO, "Components: "+ componentsGrid.getRecords());
```

Anyone having a hint? Help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand well your requirement you want to read all the rows of the grid and store their data in a db.
I think you can use:
`getRecordList()` which *Return the underlying data of this DataBoundComponent as a RecordList.
You will be able to iterate inside this list, extract the attribute value you want for every record and store these data in your db.
Or use the `getRecords()` method as you said and iterate in the array of `ListGridRecord` obtained.

To iterate through your RecordList you have to transform it to an array, for example with a lot of dummy objects and methods:

```
RecordList data = MyGrid.getRecordList();
for(Record record : data.toArray()){
    MyDataObject obj = new MyDataObject()
    obj.setId(record.getAttribute("thId"));
    obj.setOne(record.getAttribute("anAttribute"));
    obj.setTwo(record.getAttribute("anotherAttribute"));
    obj.StoreToDb();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Yes you got me right. However, so far I wasn't able to achieve what you wrote. If I call getRecords() the API says it's only for non-databound grids and suggests to use getResultSet(). As with getRecordList() I was not able to iterate inside those sets/lists because my compiler says it's only possible for arrays. Could you provide me with an example of how to iterate in this case? I tried:
`int i = 0;
for (Record record : componentsGrid.getRecordList()){   
   logger.log(Level.INFO, "Component-ResultSet: "+ record.getAttributeAsString("componentType"));
   i++;
  }`

Comment: Thank you! I'm afraid this does not work for me. I still get null objects. Am I right to take my field names (i.e. the column-names) as the attribute names?

Comment: If you have for example such a datasource: 
sourceDS = new DataSource();
DataSourceField valeurSource = new DataSourceField("valeur", FieldType.TEXT);  
valeurSource.setPrimaryKey(true);
valeurSource.setTitle(titreSource);
sourceDS.setFields(valeurSource); 

You will use "valeur" as the attribute.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you, but it still doesen't work. If I take e.g. this showcase [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/GWT/GridDataBoundFetchSampleSmartGWT.htm) and add 
`RecordList data = countryGrid.getRecordList();
  for(Record record : data.toArray()){
   GWT.log(record.getAttribute("countryCode"));
  }`
I would expect to get listed all data belonging to the "countryCode"-column. Instead, I get nothing. If I add another `countryGrid.fetchData(new Criteria("countryCode", "US"));`I get several null-printouts. What am I doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: With this code do you have the records displayed in the grid ?